# how can I color-scrolling in heatmap.2

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

how can I do color-scrolling for the Color-Key in heat map.2 ?
I mean I want to show the blue-area only.
[image]

```
heatmap.2(mat, Rowv = F, Colv = F, dendrogram = "none", trace = "none", 
          col = bluered(100), key = TRUE, key.xlab = "", key.ylab = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The question here is a bit unclear. It seems like you are asking about how to edit the dendrogram. There should be a reorder parameter that you can edit to get the effect you would want.[Link to heatmap.2 function from gplots package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gplots/versions/3.0.1.1/topics/heatmap.2)

Comment: I have log10 (p value) for data and I want to make cutoff so that only the blue part is shown. this means that the white area is shifted to -2 e.g. instead of 0.
How can I do that?

Comment: Try changing the colsep parameter. This should help to manipulate the partitioning of colors. You will need to change colsep and rowsep through changing the sepwidth parameter for this function. It appears that the default is still being used here which is (.05,.05).

Comment: There are these options sepcolor = "blue", sepwidth = c (1, 1), I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work. I don't know what the problem is.